# clicking a button in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

i'm trying to get my web driver to click a button to go to the next page located in the bottom right corner of the page, but it seems that no matter what type of selector i choose it wont do anything, here's the button

```
<button class="css-1eamy6l-unf-pagination-item" aria-label="Laman berikutnya"><svg class="unf-icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24" fill="var(--N400, #6C727C)" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;"><path d="M9.5 17.75a.75.75 0 01-.5-1.28L13.44 12 9 7.53a.75.75 0 011-1.06l5 5a.75.75 0 010 1.06l-5 5a.74.74 0 01-.5.22z"></path></svg></button>
```

[image: screenshot of the button code]

link to the page:
[link to the page](https://www.tokopedia.com/search?st=product&q=frying%20pan&srp_component_id=01.07.00.00&srp_page_id=&srp_page_title=&navsource=)

my current code to get the webdriver to click the button is

```
driver.find_element("class name","css-1eamy6l-unf-pagination-item").click()
or
driver.find_element("css selector","button[aria-label='Laman berikutnya']").click()
```

i tried to use xpath too and it didn't work either, any idea?

Comment: The answer below updated, please try.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's would be like this if you are using a recent update of selenium

For **CSS Selector**

```
button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".fa.fa-sign-in.btn-primary")

button.click()
```

For **html tag name**

```
sign_up_button = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,"button")
sign_up_button.click()
```

Comment: it still won't do anything, is it because of the button itself doesn't contain a href link?

Comment: can you add the line or any screenshot for better understanding about your button's code??

Comment: i have edited the post to show the screenshot of the button's code on the website

Answer (score 0):

You have correct locator, by `css selector` with value `button[aria-label='Laman berikutnya']`.

But the problem is you need scroll the web page to trigger this element until appear.

Add some logic like below, put scroll function inside `loop` and check with **`driver.find_elements`*** as a indicates that it appears or not:

```
driver.get(link to the page)

y=500
while len(driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[aria-label='Laman berikutnya']")) == 0:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, " +str(y) +")")
    y+=500

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[aria-label='Laman berikutnya']").click()
```

Note : You need to count the number of loops to prevent if the element never appears.

Comment: it still won't do anything, is it because of the button itself doesn't contain a href link?

Comment: @Treemore can you make sure the element only 1 `By.CLASS_NAME, 'css-1eamy6l-unf-pagination-item'`?

Comment: there's actually two i just checked, one for the go back (which is disabled on the first page), and the second one which i want to go to the next page

Comment: @Treemore I suspect this code go to the first, disable button. because by default it will match the first. Please try with this xpath : `(By.XPATH, '(//button[@class="css-1eamy6l-unf-pagination-item"])[2]')`

Comment: nope, still won't go to the next page and exit the program prematurely

Comment: @Treemore please provide more HTML, with current pagination

Comment: i have added link to the page in the post, feel free to check it, the element im trying to get is the button to the next page in the bottom right

Comment: i already tried it, im sorry for not responding, but it still won't do anything, i still suspect it might have something to do with the way the button works